# Need to force close suspicious tab/dialogue box jamming everything

Tags: safari, imac, malware, tabs, dialog

Need to force close suspicious tab without accepting a download from a dialogue box that currently has the whole browser stuck.It wants me to click "OK" to unfreeze things. The screen shot (for those who can't see images) just shows the open, blank tab - from a site called theboxfile.com, in the middle there is a dialogue window where the only option is "OK" but clicking that accepts a download of what is claimed to be a new Flash Player (um, sure it is)

[image: screenshot showing open tab and problematic dialogue box]

OK, so, I was uh... on the high sea - h'ar matey.. so, in browsing around for treasure, ad windows/tabs open. I accept that because the ad revenue funds the fleet, so to speak. But this one tab opened and I can't close it without clicking "ok" in  dialogue window. I know not to click that stuff. Clicking things will open a gate and you end up with your visa number pinged in Phuket.

I tried command + W. Nothing except that thud noise when the imac says nope. I tried moving to a different tab - thud. Is there a way to close it without accepting the download?

I'm thinking I could bookmark the tabs and then just reopen the rest after I close the entire window... NOPE. That doesn't work either. Can't access the bookmark menu options on the drop down.

I'm on a iMac, Yosemite 10.9.5 and using the most recent update of Safari (which it won't let me look at the version # atm).

Answers most appreciated. Please don't scold me for the "high seas" you don't walk in my shoes.

Answer (score 1):

That box is clearly trying to install some funny trojan on your computer. (side advice: never download Flash from anywhere that's not Adobe's website, but I'm sure you already know that if you're 'sailing the high seas'.)

Unfortunately, there's no way to avoid closing everything. The only way out of this is to force-quit Safari through Force Quit - the keystroke 'Option-Command-Escape (⌥⌘⎋)'. This would bring the Force Quit menu into focus, allowing you to close Safari and ultimately the problematic tab. The good thing about Force Quit is that it always stays on top and in focus, so the tab shouldn't be able to steal focus from the menu.

[image: Force Quit]

*The Force Quit menu. As you can see, the current open application is highlighted automatically.*

If Safari tries to reopen the closed tabs, ⌥⌘⎋ it again. The next time it starts, it shouldn't try to reopen the closed tabs.

It's probably a good idea to track down which site/tab caused this dialog to show up and either inform the webmaster or avoid visiting the site for a few weeks for your safety. Additionally, you may want to [disable auto-opening of "safe" files by Safari](http://browsers.about.com/od/safar1/ht/safarisafefiles.htm).